# Is `^/` a chracter type in PCRE?

Tags: regex, pcre

Is `^/` a chracter type in PCRE?

Have seen it get mentioned in character classes. e.g. `[^/]*`.

Cannot find anything in [Documentation](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The caret `^` at the **beginning** of a character class denotes negated character classes. So `[^/]*` means zero or more characters other than `/`, and `[^0-9]+` matches any string of characters without any digits etc.

[More details can be found here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)